# .htaccess is not working on ubuntu

Tags: server, permissions, .htaccess

I want to give

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /draft/ on this server.
```

so added .htaccess to folder with

`Options -Indexes`

But it's not working on ubuntu server and displaying folder files. Its working on my local system (windows) though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the websever has read access to the location. So for a path of `/var/www/drafts` and to give the web server read + write access

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/drafts
sudo find /var/www/drafts -type f  -exec chmod 640 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/drafts -type d  -exec chmod 750 {} \;
```

It's unclear from your question if you want it to list files or not but:

If you want to show a listing of files for /drafts

You need to do

```
Options +Indexes
```

`-Indexes` removes the option

Comment: `chown` without `sudo`?

Comment: @A.B. added sudo,  Too many CentOS days of being root for this stuff.

Comment: =) yes, it's confusing